# Customer segmentation variable selection

Tags: r, regression, probability, clustering

I am trying to do customer segmentation based on their past purchase pattern on different segments like milk products, frozen products, alcohol, grocery and so on

I also have each customer's information like age, gender, education level, total members in house and dozen of other other customer's information.

My objective is to group customers based on their purchase pattern on different segments.

I am not sure what sought of information shall I consider while doing clustering? Shall I consider all variables(past purchase on each segments and customer's info) mentioned above? If not then what variables would be relevant?
In the end I want to see what type of customer features falls in each segment and are they differ from other segments?

Please suggest.

Comment: Hi, I am on the similar problem as well. Any  suggestions that you can share? did you manage to solve this?

Comment: What is did was segmented the customers based on their purchase pattern and retained theirs id. Post segmentation (got 4 cluster) those ids are mapped to their respective profile.

Comment: Did you encounter a problem like this when segmenting? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/577253/infer-limits-of-unscaled-values-from-their-standardized-values-clustering