# Infer limits of unscaled values from their standardized values - Clustering

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, k-means, unsupervised-learning, lognormal-distribution

I am working on a clustering problem and I have some skewed variables.

So, I log transform them and use them in clustering.

However, instead of multivariate clustering, I do multiple univariate clustering (1D clustering of multiple variables seperately) using jenks approach.

My question is,

a) The pattern/cluster/cluster labels found based on standardized/log transformed values also apply to the original values? For ex: using log transformed values (and their correspondimg customer id), I can get their raw values. So, can I say that raw data from `100` to `102` belongs to cluster 0 and `800` to `804` belongs to cluster 1?

Meaning, the pattern found for normalized/standardized/transformed value are also applicable to raw values? Or is it like pattern found in log transformed values is kind of fake (amd not mecessarily apply to raw values)

my sample data looks like below. This is just dummy data to help understand the question (so transformation values may be incorrect)

[image]

Comment: How do you combine the univariate results into an overall cluster solution?

Comment: @whuber - based on some biz logic.

Comment: if variable 1 value belongs to Cluster 1 and variable 2 value belongs to Cluster 3  and variable 3 value belongs to cluster 4 then final_cluster_label = "High spenders"

if variable 1 value belongs to Cluster 3 and variable 2 value belongs to Cluster 4  and variable 3 value belongs to cluster 1 then final_cluster_label = "Champions"

Comment: something like above...here by variable value, I meam log transformed values.

Comment: since number of variables is low, we write a if else logic.. we have 5 variables (5 1d clustering)..

Comment: This is my related post on the same topic - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/576980/multiple-univariate-clustering-vs-single-multivariate-clustering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're basically asking: "If I apply a log-transform to my data and run a clustering analysis on the transformed data, are the conclusions/patterns valid for the *original* data?"

Maybe someone can provide a formal theoretical/mathematical answer, but from a practical point of view, what you're describing is quite common and generally considered valid.

You should be a bit careful when you do this (especially in settings like regression - if you do regression on log-values, don't forget that the coefficients are *for log-values* and you have to do some transformation to get the raw value interpretation).

In your case, though, I think this kind of approach is perfectly fine. But you should think about the problem from a "common sense" standpoint and understand why your clustering might be better/different with the log-transformed values than with the original values, and whether that makes sense in your context (presumably, the log "squeezes" your skewed distribution, making sparse points closer together and therefore easier to cluster).

Comment: Thanks. When log squeezes the raw data (so its able to find patterns because points are squeezed), how can that be applicable for their raw data (which can far from each other)?

Comment: for ex : if I say cluster 1's limit is from 800 to 804? Is that correct? (Though the cluster label was actually found using log values)

Comment: @TheGreat I'm not sure it's really correct to define the "limits" of a cluster (unless the algorithm somehow explicitly provides that, which I'm not sure really exists). I think you can only really say that points 1, 5, 12, 15 etc. belong to cluster 1.

Comment: Sorry, may I know which points are you  referring as `1,5,12 and 15`? because I don;t have such points in my sample above?

Comment: Additionally, can I know why not the limits be inferred? because, we agree that these points/customers belong to cluster 1. Now, I investigate each of these clusters (using their customer ids) and find out the variable (original variable - unstandardized) minimum value for ex: 10, and max limit for the same variable is 120. In this can't we consider that any customers with a variable value of this limit, would fall into cluster 1

Comment: Because if we tell to a business user that this cluster is created on salary value limit of 1.3 to 3.3 (which are standardized/log transformed values). This wouldn;t make sense to them. Whereas if we could get the corresponding original/raw value using the customer id, then it would make more sense to the business. Isn't it?

Comment: can you also given me an example scenario if possible to illustrate why this may not work?

Comment: @TheGreat Sorry, "points 1, 5, 12 and 15" are not from your data, that was just a random example of the output of some clustering.

Comment: @TheGreat I think this depends on your algorithm (whether you can use such ranges). I had never heard of Jenks Natural Breaks classification (if that's what you're using), and for that algorithm, it might actually be possible to do what you're saying. However, the basic reason is this: You're saying if cluster 1's biggest salary value is 3.3, that means that the max boundary for this cluster is 3.3 . However, this isn't necessarily the case - what if you add a new point to your data with salary 3.31 - are you sure this point will be classified in a different cluster?

Comment: @TheGreat If it's put in the same cluster, suddenly your range is now 3.31, not 3.3 . Then you get a new point that's 3.35 - are you sure that won't be put in this cluster? I hope you understand what I'm illustrating. Especially in the multivariate case, generally there aren't "hard" boundaries - when you add new data, it also changes the distribution, which might change your clustering. If you keep adding data, you'll find 'boundaries" change, new clusters might appear etc. Because of this, I don't think it really makes sense to put boundaries on your clusters.

Comment: @TheGreat Imagine you have two clusters - cluster A has max salary at 3.3 and cluster B has MIN salary at 5.1 . So, where is the boundary? You might say boundary for cluster A is at 3.3 , but how do you know? The boundary could be anywhere between 3.3 and 5.1, maybe you just don't have any data points in that range to demonstrate the "actual" boundary. Maybe the "true boundary" is at 4.2 , but you just don't know. Yet at the same time, if you start adding points at 4.2, maybe there'll eventually be a cluster C from 3.9-4.2 . I hope this shows why conceptually I don't think this makes sense.

Comment: Yes. Correct So, everytime, we hve new data points, shohldn't we rerun the cluster? And get new cluster limits? The limit that we see right now is applicable only for this execution...once I get the clustering oytput, i investigate them and find out this characteristics.. but later after 2 months, if I get new 1000 points, tgen I will rerun clustering. Which will hve new limits later on..So, am I right to understand this way?

Comment: In addition to tge above, my qiestion  mainly on raw values and standardized values. As you might know for kmeans clustering, we are expected to stabdardize our input data etc. So, lets take I standardize my salary variable..and cluster 1 has salary value from 1.1 to 3.4..but when I communicate the characteristocs of this cluster 1, i cannot tell them this cluster 1 has salary range (with this data run) of 1.1 to 3.4..it may not make semse to them. So, they my question is,instead of 1.1, can I say raw value whoch is 100 usd to 3.4 (whoch is 300 usd) the range of salary value for this cluster?

Comment: @TheGreat Yes, I would re-run the clustering when you have significant updates of data. However, my point was to explain that saying "Cluster A's boundary is at 3.1" just doesn't make sense because you don't know where the exact boundary/cutoff is. The most you can say is "We can see that the salaries of all members of cluster B are from 1.1 to 2.0 " . But that doesn't mean that the cluster is *defined* by those values

Comment: @TheGreat Yes, that's exactly correct. You standardize the values, then you run clustering, then to give salary ranges for the clusters, you simply undo the transformation you used to standardize them. So if the cluster has salaries from 1.1 to 3.4, you convert that back to, for example, 100 usd to 300 usd and report that